# SQL Server 2005: stored procedure to move rows from one table to another

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I have 2 tables of identical schemea. I need to move rows older than 90 days (based on a dataTime column present in the table) from table A to table B. Here is the pseudo code for what I want to do

```
SET @Criteria = getdate()-90

Select * from table A
Where column X<@Criteria
Into table B

--now clean up the records we just moved to table B, in Table A
delete from table A Where column X<@Criteria
```

My questions are:

1. What is the most efficient way to do this (will select-in perform well under high volumes)? Table A will have ~180,000,000 rows in it, and will need to move ~4,000,000 rows at a time to table B.
2. How do I encapsulate this under one transaction so that I will not delete rows from Table A if there was an error inserting them to Table B. I just want to make sure that I don't accidentally delete a row from table A unless I have successfully written it to table B.
3. Are there any good SQL Server 2005 books that you recommend?

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it

Comment: Is this a scheduled / triggered task? How frequently do you need to do this?

Comment: Well my thoughts are that this stored procedure would get executed from a SSIS package that would be scheduled to run twice a day.

Comment: I'm a SSIS newbie, but from my understanding of SSIS wouldn't I still need to write a stored proc in the database, then envoke that proc from a SSIS package?? or am i missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that SSIS is probably the best solution for your needs.

I think you can just use the SSIS tasks like [Data Flow task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141122.aspx) to achieve your needs. There doesnt seem to be any need to create a procedure separately for the logic.

Transactions can be set for any Data Flow task using TransactionOption property. [Check out this article as to how to use Transactions in SSIS](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1585)

Some basic tutorials on SSIS packages and how to create them can be referred to [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365330.aspx) and [here](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/sql/UsingSQLServerIntegrationServicesDataFlowSQLServer2005.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

regarding
*How do I encapsulate this under one transaction so that I will not delete rows from Table A if there was an error inserting them to Table B.*

you can delete all rows from A that are in B using a join.  Then, if the copy to B failed, nothing will be deleted from A.

Comment: great idea, I'll try that for my delete